# Debugging a boost converter (TPS61220)

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc-dc-converter, boost, debugging

I'm trying to debug a incorrect output voltage from a boost regulator ([TPS61220](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs776b/slvs776b.pdf)). The schematic is below. Pointed colors represent the measuring points in graphs underneath:

[image]

The graphs show the circuit behavior. 
[image]

The graph below is the input voltage and the L voltage captured with an oscilloscope:
[image]

According to the datasheet, the ratio of R1 and R2 should result in an output voltage of cca. 2.8V. However the output (green) is never higher than the input and is rather unstable. The current coming from the source is a constant 15mA even though there is nothing connected to the output.

The prototype board was assembled on a breadboard.

The power source is expected to be unstable, vary in voltage between 0.8-2.5.

Questions:

- How would one approach debugging this circuit?
- Should the current be observed on the induct and it makes no sense to check the voltage (green)?
- Would 15mA of current without a consumer imply an assembly problem?

Comment: Why do you have your feedback divider (R1/R2) connected to Vin?!? How is the IC supposed to know what its output is if you're not giving it any feedback from that output?

Comment: That looks like a good answer to me @brhans

Comment: also, what kind of supply collapses to 1.5V under a 50mA load? You may have unrealistic expectations of a too-small battery - it is trying, Vout > Vin from 21 to about 30s (but only just)

Comment: Brhans answered it correctly but I just wanted to add that your oscillograms are in several orders of magnitude too slow on the time scale to be of any use. Try to capture a few cycles of operation.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It's the source that I'm interested in testing. It is volatile and low power (solar cell) and I'm trying to find a regulator that would provide a stable voltage output.

Comment: A "detail" like that ought to be in the question. What you're looking for is much more like an MPPT tracker, and you cannot expect it to produce a stable output voltage unless you can control the current demanded by the load. (Also the datasheet link is now broken). First question on the revised circuit is, why aren't you seeing teh oscillations?

Comment: What is the value of C2? It shows 0.1mF - are you really using 100uF?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Wanted to get the circuit running with a higher power source (battery) and later switch to a lower power one (solar cell). In case it stopped working then, would attribute it to low currents of the solar cell. `you cannot expect it to produce a stable output voltage unless you can control the current demanded by the load` is this some kind of a general rule? Was perceiving the only limiting factor to be the power the input power of the source.

Comment: @PeterSmith That was the one I had at the moment of making the circuit. The datasheet limits the lover values only, this one is 10x bigger than the original but would expect to see clearer effects on the output signal if it was the problem?

Comment: @Alan: it is *possible* that the initial inrush current takes the part to current limit; the main switch will turn off, and once the current limit is removed, the part would switch on the output again, but quite possible restarting the current limit with this issue repeating for quite some time (and possibly never recovering). To see that would require somewhat faster sampling.

Comment: No, I meant in the context of a solar cell or other current limited supply. (Datasheet link OK again, thanks). Also worth linking to the inductor's datasheet.

Comment: With the updated schematic and correct FB, do you have any swithcing waveform on SW? Again, no logger, get an oscilloscope. What's your input voltage? Is EN high?

Comment: @winny Updated the question with the graph from the oscilloscope. It also shows the input voltage which is the voltage on EN.

Comment: Good! Did you burn it out? Looks like it's trying to switch but fails to do so. 15 mA without load = damaged circuit.

Answer (score 4):

In order to regulate the output voltage, the IC needs to know what that voltage is.
Some ICs have an internal connection to this point in the circuit and usually an internal fixed voltage divider network which is compared to an internal reference.

If the IC is intended to have an adjustable output voltage (like yours), the usual method is to have the user/designer incorporate their own voltage divider, allowing a range of output voltages to be selected.
You choose the resistor values to achieve a division ratio such that when your desired output voltage is achieved, the value produced by the voltage divider matches the value of the IC's internal reference.
This divider of yours is connected to the **feedback** pin on the IC.

BUT - you have connected your voltage divider to your input supply voltage instead of the output - so your IC has no idea what the output voltage is.
Its not getting any feedback, so it can't regulate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer brhans. I made a mistake in the drawings when posting the question. Updated the image and graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Your VFB voltage is at 20mV, while the datasheet specifically shows it should be at 500mV. That explains why you don't get the expected output voltage. As to why the VFB is so low, you need to investigate that more.